# What's a word for someone you know very well, but you're not friends?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

You've known each other for years. You've talked for hours at a time before. You regularly interact in person and/or online.

It's not that you don't like them. You're just neutral to them. You neither like or dislike spending time with them. It's something that's happened over time due to shared groups or work/school.

So, you wouldn't call this person a friend, but you're more than acquaintances because of your knowledge of each other and length of the relationship.

What word would you use for this?

Comment: You still regularly interact with the person. Why? If it happens in a particular context you could say work friend or school friend or neighbour or fellow commuter, fellow choir member etc. Or if you are adult and say school friend it shows you are not quite still friends. Mostly though if you are looking for a way to indicate you don't particularly like someone who you see as often as a friend there may be no polite way of doing this. Casual friend. Could youplease give more context?

Answer (score -1):

Colleague

Merriam-Webster:  an associate or coworker typically in a profession or in a civil or ecclesiastical office and often of similar rank or status : a fellow worker or professional.

Colleague does not have to be same profession or work environment, but rather emphasis on peer with shared (not necessarily joint) activities.

Comment: “Well-acquainted.”

Comment: Maybe not always, but I think "colleague" usually implies someone you know from the workplace, whereas "acquaintance" doesn't have that allusion.